# UsrClass.dat not loading when booting directly into profile

Tags: windows-7, login, user-profiles, acl, autologon

Came across a strange issue with Windows 7 on 7 April 2018. Suddenly my computer would not load UsrClass.dat due to the file being open. This Means that the desktop is loaded without my personal settings (as such not a temp profile). This is logged as events 1508 and 1542. I have restored the file several times - the file is not corrupt.

After many hours of restore, trial and error, testing etc. I have come up with a workaround.

Originally my system boots directly into one users account (AutoLogon). There were no other accounts on the system.

To work around the issue I have put a password on my profile (and setting AutoLogon to 0 in registry). This gives Windows some time before finally loading the user profile. In other words, the mysterious handle on UsrClass.dat is gone and the profile is loaded normally.

I find it a bit annoying to do this workaround since I have come to like just turning on the system and doing other stuff while the profile is fully loaded - without interference from the password/logon screen.

So, I'm looking for the real solution to this problem. Why is there a "handle" on the UsrClass.dat file? How do I figure out why the file is in use at boot? Why does it help to "delay" boot, e.g. with a preshell chkdsk-command?

I have checked the ACL's on the file and registry and they're as per default. Sfc /scannow had all in the green and I've checked the system several times for virus. Also no strange entries according to Autoruns.

Suggestions as to how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

After running with two profiles for a while I deleted the other profile and everything seems to be working again. From failing all the time I have had 10 boots directly into Windows without problems. I deleted the other profile after Windows booted into a temp profile even when the above workaround was in place. Maybe the system profile was corrupt and fixed at that point.

Other than that I cannot figure out what did it. I had a scheduled task running at system start that I have disabled. Other than that I have changed nothing.

Let's hope it stays healthy. OS may be an abbreviation of OrganiSm...